# inform TableView to reload by changes to other ManagedObjectContext

Tags: iphone, core-data, tableview, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have an Core Data iPhone application that uses 2 contexts. One to display the data in a TableView and another for importing data. After importing I proceed a save on the import context. In my AppDelegate I'm listening for NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification to merge the main context with the information of the imported data by the notification.
My problem is that the TableView that uses the main context and displays the (imported) data doesn't update. Do I anyhow have to inform him to do anything to refresh?